# Rust Global.dealloc vs ptr::drop_in_place vs ManuallyDrop

Tags: pointers, rust, destructor, allocation

I'm relatively new to Rust. I was working on some lock-free algorithms, and started playing around with manually managing memory, something similar to C++ new/delete. I noticed a couple different ways that do this throughout the standard library components, but I want to really understand the differences and use cases of each. Here's what it seems like to me:

`ManuallyDrop<Box<T>>` will prevent Box's destructor from running. I can save a raw pointer to the `ManuallyDrop` element, and have the actual element go out of scope (what would normally be dropped in Rust) without being dropped. I can later call `ManuallyDrop::drop(&mut *ptr)` to drop this value manually.

I can also dereference the `ManuallyDrop<Box<T>>` element, save a raw pointer to just the `Box<T>`, and later call `std::ptr::drop_in_place(box_ptr)`. This is supposed to destroy the `Box`itself and drop the heap-allocated `T`.

Looking at the `ManuallyDrop::drop` implementation, it looks those are literally doing the exact same thing. Since `ManuallyDrop` is zero cost and just stores a value in it's struct, is there any difference in the above two approaches?

I can also call `std::alloc::Global.dealloc(...)`, which looks like it will deallocate the memory block without calling drop. So if I call this on a pointer to `Box<T>`, it'll deallocate the heap pointer, but won't call `drop`, so `T` will still be lying around on the heap. I could call it on a pointer to `T` itself, which will remove `T`.

From exploring the standard library, it looks like `Global.dealloc` gets called in the  `raw_vec` implementation to actually remove the heap-allocated array that `Vec` points to. This makes sense, since it's literally trying to remove a block of memory.

`Rc` has a drop implementation that looks roughly like this:

```rust
// destroy the contained object
ptr::drop_in_place(self.ptr.as_mut());

// remove the implicit "strong weak" pointer now that we've
// destroyed the contents.
self.dec_weak();

if self.weak() == 0 {
    Global.dealloc(self.ptr.cast(), Layout::for_value(self.ptr.as_ref()));
}
```

I don't really understand why it needs both the `dealloc` and the `drop_in_place`. What does the `dealloc` add that the `drop_in_place` doesn't do?

Also, if I just save a raw pointer to a heap-allocated value by doing something like `Box::new(5).into_raw()`, does my pointer now control that memory allocation. As in, will it remain alive until I explicitly call `ptr::drop_in_place()`?

Finally, when I was playing with all this, I ran into a strange issue. After running `ManuallyDrop::drop` or `ptr::drop_in_place` on my raw pointer, I then tried running `println!` on the pointer's dereferenced value. Sometimes I get a scary heap error and my test fails, which is what I would expect. Other times, it just prints the same value, as if no drops happened. I also tried running `ManuallyDrop::drop` multiple times on the exact same value, and same thing. Sometimes a heap error, sometimes totally fine, and the same value prints out.

What is happening here?

Comment: Your question would probably be better off as several more concise questions: i.e. "what is the difference between `dealloc` and `drop`", "how does `Rc` work", "what happens when I dereference a deallocated pointer", etc.

Comment: I think the question was excellent and very well articulated.

Answer (score 5):

If you come from C++, you can think of `drop_in_place` as calling the destructor manually, and `dealloc` as calling old C `free`.

They serve different purposes:

- `drop_in_place` just calls `Drop::drop`, that releases the resources held by your type.
- `dealloc` frees the memory pointed to by a pointer, previously allocated with `alloc`.

You seem to think that `drop_in_place` also frees the memory, but that is not the case. I think your confusion arises because `Box<T>` contains a dynamically allocated object, so its `Box::drop` implementation does release the memory used by that object, after calling its `drop_in_place`, of course.

That is what you see in the `Rc` implementation, first it calls the `drop_in_place` (destructor) of the inner object, then it releases the memory.

About what happens if you call `drop_in_place` several times in a row... well, the function is unsafe for a reason: you most likely get *Uundefined Behavior*. From the docs:

> ...if T is not `Copy`, using the pointed-to value after calling `drop_in_place` can cause undefined behavior.

Note the `can cause`. I think it is perfectly possible to write a type that allows calling `drop` several times, but it doesn't sound like such a good idea.